# How to set downtime duration for datadog downtime recuring weekly

Tags: terraform, datadog

I'm trying to create a datadog monitor that only alerts on Wednesdays and Fridays. I have created the metric and monitor, and I think the best solution is to create a schedualed downtime that repeats for the days I'm not interessted in.

Ive created the downtime window as:

```
resource "datadog_downtime" "rm_snapshot" {
  scope = ["*"]
  start = 1556841600

  disabled = false
  monitor_id = "${module.RM_snapshot.monitor_id}"

  recurrence = {
    period = 1
    type = "weeks"
    week_days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Thu", "Sat"]
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["start", "end"]
  }
}
```

This creates a window for only 1hr, ideally this should be 24hr

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `start` and `end` tags with a 24 hour window?

Comment: Thanks for responding. From reading https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/datadog/r/downtime.html#start I can see that it takes a posix timestamp for those tags. And ive tried a few things from 0000 to 9999etc,  or specifically putting in a time from epoch for midnight tonight and this morning. But I get errors like : `400 Bad Request: {"errors":["Scheduled downtime start cannot be in the past"]}`